# Is possible that pain will start epileptic seizure?

Tags: pain, neurology, seizure, triggers, epilepsy

In August of 2015, I have experience with something new, related to neurology and probably also cardiology. I described it in [Neurosciences](https://plus.google.com/+V%C3%A1clavMac%C5%AFrek/posts/8YhK4jk784u) community on G+ (where you can read all text, together with additional comment).

> After cycling fall, I visited surgery ambulance for re-dressing of wounds - but there I passed something that looked like absence epilepsy attack. But from my view it was only nausea caused by pain released by removing of old dressing of wounds.
>
> EEG was clear of anything showing epilepsy. CT disproved intracranial hemorrhage - but revealed hypoplasia of left arteria vertebralis.

I would not like to question if doctor on neurology ward was right that it was not epileptic seizure (I have not reason to don't believe her).

I only would like to know if is possible that pain will trigger epileptic serizure.

Sources in my language (that I found) do not call pain as trigger. They only repeat common triggers.

Answer (score 4):

*There are several parts in your question.*

> Does pain trigger epileptic seizure?

To answer this question, it is essential to understand what is an epilepsy. **An epilepsy arises when the normal pattern of neuronal activity is disturbed** (ie the epileptogenic threshold is altered). This involves different cellular and molecular alterations: change in neuronal connections (lesions in the neuronal pathways), neuronal signalling (alteration in neurotransmitter availability or in neurotransmitter receptors), etc...

In the literature, some describe **internal factors** (such as hormones, electrolytes, state of consciousness and body temperature) and **external factors** (sensory or electrical) that may reduce the epileptogenic threshold and hence trigger a seizure.

One study, including more than 400 patients which were asked to describe the triggering factors of their last seizures, identified m**issing medication (40.9%), emotional stress (31.3%), sleep deprivation (19.7%), fatigue (15.3%), missing meals (9.1%), fever (6.4%), and smoking (6.4%) as the most common triggering factors**. However, **pain was also reported as a possible triggering factors, altough less common compared to the above mentionned factors**. Considering that pain is associated with different molecular (neurotransmitter concentration alteration) and cellular alterations in the brain, it is understandable that pain can be a trigger for seizure.

Now to your second question

> I would not like to question if doctor on neurology ward was right
>   that it was not epileptic seizure (I have not reason to don't believe
>   her).

**Loss of consciousness is not always due to a seizure.** You could also have experienced a **vasovagal syncope** in response to the ongoing procedure (and the pain associated with it). Indeed, **syncope is defined as a transient and self-terminating loss of consciousness (LOC) with rapid onset, short duration combined with spontaneous, prompt and complete recovery. Pain is a known triggering factor for vasovagal syncope (a subtype of reflex syncope).** The fact that your EEG did not show any evidence for an epileptic seizure (and your CT did not find any structural anomaly which would trigger a seizure) further suggests a possible vasovagal syncope. ***Of course, this comment is only based on the description you provided and should not be taken for a "final diagnosis".***

*Sources:*

Epilepsy. Pubmed Health Library. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmedhealth/PMHT0023036/

Reflex Seizures and Reflex Epilepsies. Chapter 13. The Epilepsies: Seizures, Syndromes and Management. Panayiotopoulos CP.
Oxfordshire (UK): Bladon Medical Publishing; 2005.

Balamurugan E et al. Perceived trigger factors of seizures in persons with epilepsy. Seizure. Volume 22, Issue 9, November 2013, Pages 743–747

Aydin MA et al. Management and therapy of vasovagal syncope: A review. World Journal of Cardiology. 2010;2(10):308-315. doi:10.4330/wjc.v2.i10.308.